# Algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Finding intersection of two arrays can be done if you sort the 2 arrays and then do a linear step through to record the common elements. 
This would take O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n)

Alternatively, you could compare each element in the first array with each element in the second array and you would get a O(n^2) run-time complexity.

How can I prove the first approach is better than the second?

Comment: Because the limit of n log n / n^2 as n approaches infinity is 0, which means n log n is smaller for big enough values of n. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you just did.  You just need to write it up formally.

Comment: so even if we add the three terms together O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n) .. it is always going to be smaller than O(n^2) ?

Comment: The first approach is not necessarily better for all inputs. Only if you know the actual constants hidden by the O() notation can you find the "cutoff" point (or at least an approximation to it) where the asymptotically better algorithm should start "winning".

Comment: @Pan: Yes, because there will always be values of c1, c2 and n for which c1 * n * lg(n) < c2 * n^2

Comment: What do you mean by "better", and why do you have to prove it? If asymptotic runtime is your metric of better, I'd say you're done: O(n log n) is asymptotically smaller than O(n^2).

Comment: @abeln - what inputs are you talking about ? Can you think of one set of inputs where the 2nd one will be better ?

Comment: @abeln That's not what Big-O notation implies.  Big-O is "worst case runtime" meaning you are iterating over an absurdly large array.  The big kicker is that you have to make sure you are focusing on the right variable.  If you have a function that is `processFile(file)` then yes, it is O(1) per file.  But if you go into `processFile` you could see that *per file* the runtime could actually be O(n^2)

Comment: Again, it all depends on the implementation. It might be the case that, for a small array, the overhead of sorting and the sweep is larger than simply comparing all pairs. I doubt this is what you're looking for, though.

Comment: @Pan If you had two arrays of a single element each, the second method is superior.

Comment: @Thebigcheeze: I was just pointing out that, if the constants hidden by the O() notation are large, asymptotically less efficient algorithms might be actually faster for smaller inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n)` doesn't make much sense, since `O(f)` is a set, not a number.

What you mean is `O(nlogn + nlogn + n)`, which can be shown to be equal to `O(nlogn)`. Just look at what it means for a function `f` to belong to the set `O(g)`:

`f` is an element of `O(g)` iff there exists `c>0` and `x0` such that for all `x>x0`:

`|f(x)| <= c*|g(x)|`

By setting `f=nlogn` and `g=nlogn+nlogn+n`, it follows that `f` is in `O(g)`, and hence that `O(nlogn) == O(nlogn + nlogn + n)`.

Comment: I've seen Big-O used on the left hand side of an equation, for example in CLRS. It's essentially used to indicate "any function in the set".

Comment: @abeln: can you give a more specific reference? CLRS chapter/paragraph would be helpful. If you happen to have the 2nd edition paperback, the page number will suffice.

Comment: @Philip: I don't have it with me right now. Now that I check, the Wikipedia page also mentions that use. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @abeln: interesting, it even discusses the issue at hand: "it would be more precise to use set notation [...] however, the use of the equals sign is customary". Being German, I prefer using correct notation over a customary wrong one, though.

Comment: BTW, here's another bummer from the same article: "O(n^c) and O(c^n) are very different. The latter grows much, much faster"

Comment: @Phillip: I would say you are shooting yourself in the foot. Try using the 'correct' notation for the following `1/(\sum_{prime p < x}) 1/p = 1/(log log x + A + O(x/log x)) = 1/log log x - O(A/log log x + x/log log x logx )`. And this is a simple example. Also what did you mean by the O(n^c) and O(c^n) being a bummer?

Comment: Indeed, that's most definitively incorrect. I think the other use is kind of intuitive, though.

Comment: @Moron: well, O(c^n) just gives you an upper bound. Not **every** member of O(c^n) grows much faster that every member of O(n^c).

Comment: @abeln: For c > 1, _every_ member of Theta(c^n) grows much faster than Theta(n^c). In any case, the wiki page is not claiming they are _disjoint_, and the statement O(n^c) != O(c^n) is most definitely true.

Comment: @Moron: Let c = 3. n^2 is O(3^n), yet it doesn't grow faster than n^3, which is O(n^3). The wiki page is not referring to Theta(c^n), but O(c^N).

Comment: @abel: See edit to previous comment and add to that since Theta(f(x)) subset of O(f(x)), the claim is true.

Comment: @Moron: what you're saying it's correct, but that's not what's written on the wiki page.

Comment: @abel: I see. The fact that they are talking about the growth of O(n^c) as compared to O(c^n) makes it incorrect, especially if it could refer to _any_ member. I suppose we could (and that is how I did) interpret the former and latter to refer to n^c and c^n here (rather than O(n^c) and O(c^n)), and thus they are claiming c^n is not in O(n^c). Anyway...

Comment: @abel: Yeah, these BigOH abuses are a pet peeve of mine :-) There are extremes which use BigOH no matter what, instead of Omega or Theta when they actually mean that and there are the other extremes which insist on using the proper definitions and set notation.

Comment: @Moron: I can see no reason to use Big-O-Notation in your example. I'd substitute every occurrence of `O(f(x))` by some variable `foo` which is defined to be `0 <= foo <= c*|f(x)|`. Increases both readability and correctness. BTW, where is your equation from? It seems to suggest that the sum of all primes up to some `x` equals `log log x` minus some positive number. Regarding your other question: I consider my citation from the WP article to be a bummer, because that's the language one would use to teach a 6 year old child. What's the meaning of "very different"? "much, much faster"?

Comment: @Philip: so the quote just happened to be incorrect by chance. Aw, and I though there was a "deeper" reason ;)

Comment: @Philip: You can make it as cumbersome (an so unreadable) as you like :-) Most mathematics textbooks use that notation. There is no issue of correctness, it is just convenient notation. As long as the meaning is clear, it is correct and _very_ convenient notation. I suggest you look at some of the threads on math.stackexchange which use this notation. ANd, that is the sum of _reciprocals_ of primes upto some number which is asymptotically log log x (which proves the divergence of the sum of reciprocals of primes and so there are infinite primes). This is a well known result in number theory.

Comment: @Moron: In that case, your initial "1/" is misleading. BTW, I was actually aware of the fact that there are infinitely many primes, but the only proof I know of is the one from Euclid (re-discovered by Gauß) which only involves arithmetic from elementary school. But it's comforting to see that there are more complicated versions of the proof out there (although admittedly, the formula says a bit more about primes than just their quantity). Maybe I'll have a look at math.SE tomorrow; it's 2am over here  :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that Big-O notation is the "worst case" run-time meaning that you are iterating over an array that is crushingly large.

O(N) + O(N) is equivalent to O(2N) which is equivalent to O(N)

Thus, O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n) is merely O(nlogn)

O(nlogn) < O(n^2)

Comment: @abeln What could be improved about my response given the context?

Comment: You could add that the comparison:  O(nlogn) < O(n^2) reduces to O(logn) < O(n) after factoring-out an 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) + O(n) = O(nlogn)

O(nlogn) < c*nlogn

O(n^2) < d*(n^2)

c*nlogn < d*(n^2)

**logn < d/c*n**

You can prove in many ways that there's an N where **logn < d/c*n** is always true.

You could even draw it.